# Reference Request: Projection from $L^1$ onto $L^2$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces, projection

Suppose that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a complete probability space.  Since $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a subspace of $L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, is there a well-defined/studied projection operator
from $L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ onto $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$?

If so, could someone provide a reference/ let me know why this topic is not commonly studied?

Comment: Certainly not a continuous one, because $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ (as a subspace) is dense in $L^1(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$.

Comment: Indeed, but is there some studied notion?